# after updating php apache no longer loads at localhost on osx 10.12.6

Tags: macos, terminal, mac, apache, php

I was trying to setup myphpadmin and it said I need to update php so I update php to 7.1 from terminal. I go to localhost and it says local server refused to connect. I restart apache then i typed `sudo apachectl restart`then `sudo apachectl start`. It said "/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist: service already loaded".

Comment: `restart` stops then starts Apache so that’s why you’re getting that message after the redundant `start`. Check your Apache configuration for errors. See what your logs say.